# How to get input values in a loop by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, loops, drop-down-menu

Here is select dropdown, this is in loop of multiple divs. how to get value of each element when we click `Cancel` button.
here am trying like this

```
    <?php  foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
<?php
       if($_order->getStatus() == 'complete' || $_order->getStatus() ==  'canceled'){}
else{ 
  ?>
  <div>
    <label class="select-label" for="cancel_reason">Choose a Reason:</label>

        <select class="cancel_reason" >
            <option value="R000001">Order Created by Mistake</option>
            <option value="R000002">Items would not arrive on time</option>
            <option value="R000003">Shipping cost is too high</option>
            <option value="R000004">Item price is too high</option>
            <option value="R000005">Need to change order details or payment method</option>
            <option value="R000006">Others</option>
        </select>
        <textarea class="reason_msg" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></br>
  </div>
  <div class="cancel_order_block">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action view"><button class="green-btn track-order-btn cancel_order"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Cancel') ?></button></a>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" class="order_id">
  </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; } ?>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require (["jquery","jquery/ui"], function($){
    $('.collapsable-accordion').collapsable({
        accordion: true,
        fx: 'slide',
        fxDuration: 300
    });
    $(".cancel_order").click(function(){
             $('.reason_msg').hide();

             var allreason_msg = $('.reason_msg'); // it will return array
                 var allorders = $('.order_id'); 
                 $.each(allreason_msg,function(){
                   console.log($(this).val());
                   });
                    $.each(allorders,function(){
                   console.log($(this).val());
                   });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Where am doing wrong Can I get help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to get the value of a select box when you click the cancel button then you can use jquery .closest(), selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a unique id in all your inputs. So that whenever you click on a button, you can get the respective values.

Please try this

```
    <div>
        <label class="select-label" for="cancel_reason">Choose a Reason:</label>
        <select class="cancel_reason" id="cancel_reason_<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>">
            <option value="R000001">Order Created by Mistake</option>
            <option value="R000002">Items would not arrive on time</option>
            <option value="R000003">Shipping cost is too high</option>
            <option value="R000004">Item price is too high</option>
            <option value="R000005">Need to change order details or payment method</option>
            <option value="R000006">Others</option>
        </select>
        <textarea class="reason_msg" rows="4" cols="50" id="reason_msg_<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>"></textarea>
        </br>
    </div>
    <div class="cancel_order_block">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action view">
            <button class="green-btn track-order-btn cancel_order" id="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>"> 
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Cancel') ?>
            </button>
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" id="order_<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" class="order_id">
    </div>
```

In your JS

```
    <script>
        $(".cancel_order").on("click", function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id"); /** order id */
            var cancel_reason = $("#cancel_reason_"+id).val();
            var reason_msg = $("#reason_msg_"+id).val();
            var order_id = $("#order_"+id).val(); /** same as id (order id) */
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Alok Mali for answering, by this modification am getting `undefined` log for all values

Comment: alert `id`. is it undefined? or it is giving a value? And also inspect your HTML by pressing `f12` what is the `id` of a button.

Comment: thank you for helping me, this method worked for me.

Comment: instead of `var id = $(this).attr("id"); /** order id */`
I used this `var id = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 1):

you need to do some thing like below

for uniqueId you can use something like this.

```
<input type="hidden" value="order_<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" class="order_id">
<textarea class="reason_msg" rows="4" cols="50" id="reason_<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>"></textarea>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var allreason_msg = $('.reason_msg'); // it will return array
 var allorders = $('.order_id'); 
 $.each(allreason_msg,function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
   })
    $.each(allorders,function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
   })
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<textarea class='reason_msg'>test</textarea><input type='hidden' value='1' class='order_id'/>
<textarea class='reason_msg'>test22</textarea><input type='hidden' value='2' class='order_id'/>
<textarea class='reason_msg'>test33</textarea><input type='hidden' value='3'class='order_id' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Negi Rox for replying. here it consoling the value of only first loop, for other loops it fetching first value

Comment: thank you for helping me, that other method worked for me.